# Old online story about hunting women on prison island?

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a story I read about 10 years ago. It's about an alternative universe where women can be convicted of a crime and killed for entertainment. If they are body type A - attractive and voluptuous - they are slaves and killed for entertainment. If type B - fit and sporty - they can be hunted for sport.

The story follows a type B women who is sent to an island and hunted. She eventually becomes the leader of a small band of women that have great success surviving until a group of Navy SEALs start hunting them.

The story ends with her and some of her group falling in love with the hunters, one of which happens to command an aircraft carrier, the Kitty Hawk. Together they start a revolution and overthrow the U.S. Government

It's somewhat similar to *The Metamorphosis of the Prime Intellect* with respect to torture.

It was such a strange story to read and I wanted to revisit it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Yeah, he hunts people for sport, but it's just so hard to meet people these days, you can't afford to be so picky."